# Convert a number sequence into a date using python? (example: 221201)

Tags: python, date

I have a bunch of number sequences like "221201" meaning the year 2022, month 12 and day 01 (so 2022-12-01). How can I convert number sequences in this format into the actual date using python?

I've tried using the dateutil library but couldn't figure out how to get it to recognize this format.

Comment: You just need to read the documentation and use the right pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

date_str = '221201'
date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%y%m%d')

print(type(date_obj))
print(date_obj)  # printed in default format
```

You can learn more about `strptime` in [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/python-string-to-datetime-strptime)

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. We should rather explain the challenge, and how our solution tackles it. Also answers should be self-contained. While links are encouraged, they should be supplementary, not essential.